# Stored Procedure for date ranges in a single column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Finding a solution to an issue in my project

I have stages associated with contracts. That is, a contract can be in either `Active` stage, `Process` stage or `Terminated` stage.

I need to get the no the days the contract was in each stage.

For example, if a contract `C1` was in `Active` stage from `20/10/2013` to `22/10/2013`, then in the `Process` stage from `22/10/2013` to `25/10/2013` and finally in `Terminated` stage from `25/10/2013` to `26/10/2013` and then again in `Active` from `26/10/2013` to `28/10/2013`, then I should get as result

- Active = 4days
- Process = 3days
- Terminated = 1day /likewise something

My table is created with these columns:

- `EntryId` (primary key)
- `StageId` (foreign key to `Stage` table)
- `ContractId` (foreign key to `contract` table)
- `DateofStageChange`

How to do this in SQL Server?

---

As asked pls find the table entries:

**EntryID | Stage ID | Contract ID | DateChange**

1       | A1       | C1           |20/10/2013

2       | P1       | C1           |22/10/2013

3       | T1       | C1           |25/10/2013

4       | A1       | C1           |26/10/2013

5       | P1       | C1           |28/10/2013

6       | T1       | C1           |Null(currently in this stage)

---

Need to use group by on Stage ID

Comment: Its better done with some sort of logging in place, which has the history of the application.

Comment: Can you show us what entries you would have in your table for this scenario?

Comment: Check my answer.  CTE will accomplish this in SQL server, though you'll have to put more information about the table names.

Comment: Make sure to get my latest edits.  I believe you want to order by ContractID, StageID and then date.

Comment: Have you tested my solution?  It will handle your test data exactly and return ContractID, StageID, DateChange.  You just need to tell me the name of this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is important to check and make sure how data is populated in your table.Based on just your sample data and also note that if your entryid is not in sequence then you can create one sequence using row_number.

```
declare @t table(EntryId int identity(1,1), StageId int,ContractId varchar(10),DateofStageChange date)
insert into @t values 
(1,'C1','2013-10-20'),(1,'C1','2013-10-22'),(2,'C1','2013-10-22'),(2,'C1','2013-10-25')
,(3,'C1','2013-10-25'),(3,'C1','2013-10-26'),(1,'C1','2013-10-26'),(1,'C1','2013-10-28') 

Select StageId,sum([noOfDays]) [totalNofDays] from 
(select a.StageId,a.ContractId,a.DateofStageChange [Fromdate],b.DateofStageChange [ToDate]  
,datediff(day,a.DateofStageChange,b.DateofStageChange) [noOfDays]
from @t a
inner join @t b on a.StageId=b.StageId and b.EntryId-a.EntryId=1)t4
group by StageId
```

Comment: This answer is the same as mine, you've just used identity for the row numbers instead of cte's `ROW_NUMBER()` and declared a temp table. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't with your current structure.

You can get the latest one by doing `datediff(d, getdate(), DateOfStageChange)`

but you don't have any history so you can't get previous status

Comment: You can get this in sql, check my answer.  I'm not sure what this actually even answers for the OP's question.

Comment: Now that I've seen the sample data, yes you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in SQL with CTE.

You didnt provide your tablenames, so you'll need to change where I've indicated below, but it would look like this:

```
;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT 
    DateofStageChange, StageID, ContractID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ContractID, StageId, DateofStageChange) AS RowNum
FROM 
    DateOfStageChangeTable  //<==== Change this table name
)

SELECT 
   a.ContractId,
   a.StageId, 
   Coalesce(sum(DATEDIFF(d ,b.DateofStageChange,a.DateofStageChange)), 'CurrentState`) as Days
FROM 
 cte AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 cte AS B   
 ON A.RowNum = B.RowNum + 1 and a.StageId = b.StageId and a.ContractId = b.ContractId
group by a.StageId, a.ContractId
```

This really is just a self join that creates a row number on a table, orders the table by StageID and date and then joins to itself.  The first date on the first row of the stage id and date, joins to the second date on the second row, then the daterange is calculated in days.

This assumes that you only have 2 dates for each stage, if you have several, you would just need to do a min and max on the cte table.

EDIT:

Based on your sample data, the above query should work well.  Let me know if you get any syntax errors and I'll fix them.

I added a coalesce to indicate the state they are currently in.